# Unable to sync except item under excluded item

Tags: unicorn

I can't seem to get this config to work and serialize the nested except . The log always stops at `Manager Root/Messages`  and then says `master:/sitecore/content/Email Managers/Manager Root/Messages/2019 (bca49277-dcc4-40a3-a37d-03accc37b7b5) because Children of /sitecore/content/Email Managers/Manager Root/Messages/ excluded`

Looking at [examples from Unicorn GitHub](https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn.Tests/Predicates/TestConfiguration.xml#L32) it seems like this config should work. What do I have wrong?

```
<include name="$(layer).$(module).EmailManagers" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/Email Managers">
      <exclude childrenOfPath="/Manager Root/Messages">
         <except name="/2019/11/18T153450/MyMessage" />
      </exclude>
</include>
```

I have tried removing the `/` at the start but same result. I have even tried just `MyMessage` in the name.

In case you want to see what the full path looks like `/sitecore/content/Email Managers/Manager Root/Messages/2019/11/18T153450/MyMessage`

On Unicorn 4.1.0 and Sitecore 9.1.1

**Update**
It seems if I just do `<except name="2019" />` I get 2019 and everything under it. But as soon as I do `<except name="2019/11" />` I don't get anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the nature of the tree and how the config needs that setup just clicked for me. You need to walk each node of the tree via an exception.

```
<exclude childrenOfPath="Manager Root/Messages">
             <except name="2019" includeChildren="false" />
             <except name="2019/11" includeChildren="false" />
             <except name="2019/11/18T153450" includeChildren="false" />
             <except name="2019/11/18T153450/MyMessage" />
           </exclude>
```